# Magento-1.9 Catalog Price Rule exemption

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a store with 4 or 5 Catalog Price Rules that apply 10%,20%, etc. off of **all** products in the store. These rules are tied to matching customer groups that make up a membership program we offer with different tiers for discounts.

Currently, the Catalog Price Rules apply to all items in the store across the board - all items get the discount at the level your membership includes.

We have released a special edition product that should be exempt from all price rules, even the Catalog Price Rules that apply to everything. This product should be sold for the listed price, regardless of what membership level you are, or what coupon code you have.

I understand how shopping cart price rules work, and how to make a product exempt from discount in the **Promotions** tab, however no rules seem to apply to the Catalog Price Rules, and customers are still seeing this special release item for a discounted price.

In the **Promotions** tab, I have created various *Actions* that seem to only apply to Shopping Cart Price Rules and have run out of ideas on how to make *Actions* for exempting a product from discount apply to the Catalog Price Rules.

Is there anything I can do since the CPR takes precedence over all other discounts?

Any advice or help would be appreciated, and if this has been asked before please advise.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you are trying to achieve - it's a bit unclear from your question.

Comment: @jscar Updated for clarity. Hope that helps a little.

Comment: have you tried assigning this special product to a category of its own, then in Conditions for catalogue price rules, add Category Is Not <productcategory> ?

Comment: I have not, but will give that a shot. Thank you.

Comment: you could also try adding a Catalog Price Rule, where the category is productcategory, apply fixed amount to "0" & Stop Further Rules Processing to "yes", and in the Rule Information tab set higher priority to this rule than the others

Comment: if you don't want to create a special category you could create an attribute, use it in promotions and assign a value to that product and then use that attribute to exclude it.

Comment: @Robin your solution worked for me. If you could make that as answer I would be glad to accept it.

Comment: @JWLKR did that a few days ago :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried assigning this special product to a category of its own, then in Conditions for catalogue price rules, add Category Is Not  ?